magento 2 captcha Ay is not a function recaptcha__en_gb.js
Suddenly google reCaptcha not loading at checkout page. Below console error is coming.
Uncaught TypeError: Ay is not a function

Same my issue.
recaptcha__en.js:600 Uncaught TypeError: Ay is not a function at recaptcha__en.js:600:139 at Array. (recaptcha__en.js:164:51) at recaptcha__en.js:598:365 at recaptcha__en.js:1035:83 Anyone can help?

Same here. But, another my project is working fine with same link (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/moV1mTgQ6S91nuTnmll4Y9yf/recaptcha__en.js). Possibly, in my case it's related to Mageplaza Recaptcha module.

We had a similar issue because window.self instance was being overridden on another js file.
Captcha started working after changing:
self = this;

To:
var self = this;


Can you please advise which file you changed this ?
